# Using jquery-ui datepicker with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, datepicker

I searched some questions in here, but didn't get any solution. I'm trying to use `datepicker` in `backbone.js` `require.js` project.

`main.js` :

```
requirejs.config({
   enforceDefine: true,
   paths: {
      "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-min",
      "underscore": "libs/underscore/underscore",
      "backbone": "libs/backbone/backbone-min",
      "jquery-ui" : "libs/jquery/jquery-ui"
   },
   shim : {
      "underscore": {
         deps: [],
         exports: "_"
       },
       "backbone": {
         deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
         exports: "Backbone"
       },
       "jquery-ui" : ['jquery']
   }
});
```

Here is my view :

```
define(["jquery","underscore","backbone","jquery-ui"], ,function($, _, Backbone,jqueryUI){

   //view code block

});
```

Just define it like this, and not yet call any function of `jquery-ui` then I got one error in my console `Error: No define call for jquery-ui http://requirejs.org docs/errors.html#nodefine`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to set enforceDefine to  false

Comment: @Evgeniy : It's working after I set `enforceDefine` to `false`, but could you just please tell me, what did it relate to the error issue about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work please set **enforceDefine** to **false**.

According to official [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html)

> enforceDefine: If set to true, an error will be thrown if a script
>   loads that does not call define() or have a shim exports string value
>   that can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

as for jquery plugin, I prefer to convert to UMD module which is much cleaner way to avoid contamination of global variable